# How to make a value available in all Liquid templates

Tags: ruby, templates, sinatra, liquid

I'm using Liquid with Sinatra and would like to make a certain value (`Sinatra::Application.environment`, specifically) available in all templates without defining it as a local in every get/post. Like so:

In app.rb (my main application file):

```
# nothing in here about the variable
get '/some/route' do
  # or here
  liquid :my_template
end
```

In app.rb--my main application file, or something I can require/include:

```
some_awesome_technique do
  def app_env
    Sinatra::Application.environment
  end
end
```

In any template:

```
<p>
  {% if environment == :development %}
    Never see this in production
  {% end %}
</p>

<!-- or even -->

<p>
  {% if dev_mode %}
    Or this...
  {% endif %}
</p>
```

I don't really care about the implementation as long as I don't have to put redundant code in every route. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
before do
  @env = Sinatra::Application.environment
end
```

then in your template:

```
{% if @env == :development %}
  Boo!
{% endif %}
```